# Specify dependency to an internal framework in Cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Is it possible to also use Cocoapod to specify dependencies of a target on internal framework projects (along with external pods)?

Answer (score 1):

if i correct understand you, - you can just load your internal project from private repo, like this

```
target 'YourTarget' do
    pod 'ProjectLoader', :git => 'git@localgit.yourcompany.com:group/ProjectLoader.git'
    pod 'CocoaLumberjack', '~> 2.3'
end
```

Comment: But that probably requires going the extra miles to package internal framework projects as pods. I just want to specify dependencies as xCode projects.

Comment: in my project, ProjectLoader - it's just xcode project in my private repo. You just need add .podspec file to your internal project. something like this https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html